# Rails, Stripe, CarrierWave, FileUpload, no such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, carrierwave, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I'm having a problem trying to upload a file to Stripe using their FileUpload API. I've implemented CarrierWave S3 to upload files on my site. I've followed all the Stripe API documentation, but for some reason it is giving me a "No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen" error.

Here is my controller code for the upload:

```
@id_upload = Stripe::FileUpload.create(
  :purpose => 'identity_document',
  :file => File.new(@user.uploaded_file.url)
)
```

this will return the "no such file" error, with the s3 link (- https://myapp.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/user/uploaded_file/1/file.png). The funny thing is when I go to that link in my browser, the uploaded file exists, and it is shown.

Any thoughts? Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: did you make it work? 

@gitastic

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the file directly from Amazon S3 to Striple File Upload.  However, I follow the following link to download the Amazon resource to download file from Amazon S3 to web server first, then send it to stripe:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/downloading-objects-from-amazon-s3-using-the-aws-sdk-for-ruby/

gemfile:

```
    gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'
```

In your client:

```
    s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
    resp = s3.get_object({ bucket:'your-bucket-name', key: current_user.stripe_managed_account.personal_id_document.file.path },
     target: '/tmp/personal_id_file_#{current_user.id}')

    stripe_file_upload =
      Stripe::FileUpload.create(
        :purpose => 'identity_document',
        :file => File.new('/tmp/personal_id_file_#{current_user.id}')
      )

    account ||= Stripe::Account.retrieve( current_user.stripe_managed_account.stripe_account_id )
    account.legal_entity.verification.document = stripe_file_upload.id
    account.save
```